# Node on Electron: FS ReadLine skips first x lines of file

Tags: node.js, electron, readline

When trying to read a file line by line using *createReadStream* and *readline*, i'm not getting all lines. The first x lines are skipped. Testing with a file containing 10000 lines the first 4000 are skipped.

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const fs = remote.require('fs');
const readline = remote.require('readline');
const instream = fs.createReadStream('test.txt'); 
const rl = readline.createInterface(instream);
let row = 0;
rl.on('line', function (line) {
  row++;
  console.log(row + ': ' + line);
});
```

Reading the file with fs.readFileSync does return all the lines.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt');
console.log(data.toString());
```

Comment: Consistently 4000? Or does it change run to run? And does your console.log command output a value for row of 1 to 6000, or 4001 to 10000?

Comment: Not consistently 4000 no... and the row outputs 1 to 6000 but the line content (also containing an line counter) starts from 4000 (in this example, but the skipped lines alter every time i try)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `createInterface` it will start reading the file and emitting `line` events, so you must ensure that `on('line', ...)` is called synchronously after `createInterface` (i.e. without any `await` or `setTimeout` callback in between).

In my case, I was randomly missing the first few hundred lines of files because I had an `await` in between `createInterface` and reading the lines:

```
const rl = readline.createInterface(stream);

const connection = await connectToDatabase(); // await causes lines to be lost!

for await (const line of rl) {
    ...
}
```